# what does this multi-dimensional array looking thing actually mean?

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface Foo {
    Bar *bar[12][8][2];
}
```

And I am wondering what that means and what it is actually doing behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bar it is an array of 12 elements. Each element is an array of 8 elements, and each element is an array of 2 pointers to "Bar" objects.

Answer (score 0):

No surprises -- It is a multi-demensional array of pointers to `Bar`s.

In MRC, reference counts are managed manually.

In ARC, they are managed for you.

Comment: Array of *pointers* to `Bar`.

Comment: @KevinGrant right -- that's implied in modern objc -- clang prohibits you from creating a objc object on the stack or asking its size using `sizeof`. will add so there is no confusion. thanks.